# how to use try catch blocks in a value returning method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am checking the uploaded image in a registration form , where i need to use try catch blocks. here is my code:

```
public bool CheckFileType(string FileName)
{
        string Ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
        switch (Ext.ToLower())
        {
            case ".gif":                   
                return true;
                break;
            case ".JPEG":                    
                return true;
                break;
            case ".jpg":                  
                return true;
                break;
            case ".png":                   
                return true;
                break;
            case ".bmp":                   
                return true;
                break;
            default:                  
                return false;
                break;
        }

}
```

please suggest me how to use the try catch blocks here.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to "use try catch blocks"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which part of your code will throw an exception, in your opinion?

Comment: and why do you use .JPEG if you look for lower case extensions?

Comment: Also you don't have to use return *and* break, because the return acts as a break anyway and ends the method.

Comment: This is a good example of bad code.

Comment: @Groo: The only thing that could throw an Exception is `Ext.ToLower()` if the `FileName` parameter was `null`. That's Exception overkill IMHO.

Comment: @Town: Actually, [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) could also throw if path contains invalid characters, but I just wanted to see the OP's opinion.

Comment: And please don't catch ArgumentNullException or NullReferenceException. That's a bug.

Comment: @Groo: Yep, sorry, you're right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [try-catch blocks with the return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602699/try-catch-blocks-with-the-return-type)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be better to do it this way,

```
 public bool CheckFileType(string FileName)
 {
    bool result = false ;

    try
     {
      string Ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
      switch (Ext.ToLower())
      {
        case ".gif":                   
        case ".JPEG":                    
        case ".jpg":                  
        case ".png":                   
        case ".bmp":                   
            result = true;
            break;
       }

      }catch(Exception e)
      {
         // Log exception 
      }
      return result;
     }
```

Comment: @Henk : noted it before you pointed, anyways thanks for a prompt friendly fire ;)

Comment: comparing ".JPEG" to `Ext.ToLower()` is unlikely to match ;)

Comment: How to use try/catch here? OK you just put them into the method's body and that's it. I like this answer

Answer (score 7):

There are plenty of ways that you can use exceptions in methods that return values:

**Place your return statement outside the try-catch**  For example:

```
T returnValue = default(T);
try
{
    // My code
}
catch 
{
    // Exception handling code
}
return returnValue;
```

**Put a return statement inside your catch**

```
try
{
    // My code
}
catch 
{
    // Handle exception
    return default(T);
}
```

**Throw an exception**

You don't **have** to return a value, the method simply has to end (e.g. reach a return statement or a throw statement). Depending on the exception its not always valid to return a value.

You should think carefully about when and how to catch and handle exceptions:

1. What might fail?
2. Why / how can they fail?
3. What should I do when they fail?

In your case:

1. The only statement that can fail is `string Ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);`, which according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) can fail if `FileName` contains. (Note that `GetExtension` doesn't return null, even if `FileName` is null).
2. This might happen if the user supplied a string that contains these invalid characters.
3. If this happens, I guess that we should return false, to indicate that the path is not valid (however this depends on the application).

So I'd probably handle exceptions like this:

```
public bool CheckFileType(string FileName)
{
    string Ext;
    try
    {
        Ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Switch statement
}
```

Note that we only catch the exception that we are expected (`ArgumentException`), and we only place the `try` statement around the statement that we expect the exception to be thrown from.

In fact its a good idea to avoid throwing and catching exceptions wherever possible - not only do they incur a performance penalty (which can cause serious problems if this method is called inside a loop), but you might inadvertently catch and handle an exception that you didn't anticipate, masking a more serious problem.

In this case we can avoid throwing the exception entirely by checking ourselves to see if `FileName` contains any invalid characters:

```
public bool CheckFileType(string FileName)
{
    if (FileName == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (FileName.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) >= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Your original method goes here
}
```

Comment: I don't like catching `ArgumentException`. I would prefer just checking the Filename for invalid characters with an if. Other than that, great answer. +1.

Comment: I think, in this particular case, if an error occurs it should bubble up the stack, and not be catched\processed in this method.

Comment: @Martinho Heh, I was just adding that as you posted :-)

Comment: Unfortunately (just read it): "The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the complete set of characters that are invalid in file and directory names." :(

Comment: @data_smith It depends on the application - in this case I'd say that either checking yourself or allowing the exception to be thrown is fine and catching / masking the exception is less favorable, however I showed it anyway as in many cases you can't help exceptions being thrown (such as in IO), and it demonstrates how to think about exceptions (what might throw? why would it throw? what should I do about it?)

Comment: @Martinho Yes **but** `GetExtension` states that it will only throw if the string contains characters returned by that method - I can only assume that it won't throw for invalid characters not in that list (no disk IO is performed, and so it doesn't need to throw).  Besides, if such a character is provided, allowing the exception to be thrown is probably the lesser of 2 evils.

Answer (score 2):

As you're not actually testing the file type (only the extension of the filename), I'd first start by renaming the method. You can make an extension method to handle it:

```
public static bool HasImageExtension(this string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        if (fileName == null) return false;

        string[] validExtensions = new string[] { ".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp" };

        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        return validExtensions.Contains(extension);
    }
    // catch the specific exception thrown if there are 
    // invalid characters in the path
    catch (ArgumentException ex) 
    {
        // do whatever you need to do to handle 
        // the fact there are invalid chars
        throw; 
    }
}
```

Which you can then call, like so:

```
string fileName = "testFileName.jpg";
bool hasImageExtension = fileName.HasImageExtension();
```

Comment: Actually, [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) could also throw if path contains invalid characters

Comment: @Groo: Yep, you're right - totally ruins my answer, time for an update ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public bool CheckFileType(string FileName)
{
    try
    {
        string Ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToLower();
        string[] okExt = ".gif|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.bmp".Split('|');

        foreach(var item in okExt)
        {
            if(Ext == item)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

And remember: **never catch exceptions you're not going to handle.** (or atleast re-throw them)

Comment: Otherwise `return false;` is what I'm missing.

Comment: Fixed issues mentioned above.

Comment: Or, you could use LINQ: `return ".gif|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.bmp".Split('|').Any(e => e.Equals(Ext));`.

Comment: I think this might be clearer; return new List<string> { ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp" }.Contains(ext);

Comment: Sadly LINQ is not always available, and in this situation we won't gain much by using LINQ.